# Visual Studio Resets Error Pages When Publishing a Web Application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

I have setup a very simple web application with a single maintenance page that will be used for a very big and complicated web site that has multiple pages and sub-folders and sub-sites etc. I setup the error elements in the web.config to point all to the Default.aspx page of the site and in order to handle someone attempting to get to an HTML page (MyPage.html) I have setup all of the entries for the Error Pages in IIS to point to this page as well.
[image]

All of this works perfectly until I republish the maintenance web site, such as I would do when I make date and time changes to the outage page. Once I publish the website using Visual Studio it resets all of these error pages back to the default error pages.

[image]

**Is there away to keep Visual Studio from doing this?**

Using Visual Studio 2010 to manage the site
Running IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Thanks
Doug